# Symfony Monolog add extra logging data only in case of an exception

Tags: symfony4, monolog

I would like to log data with monolog but only when an exception is thrown.

The purpose ist to have extra information in the log file to analyse the exception. For example:

- would like to have the reqeust logged, but only in case of an exception, not everytime
- same for the session data

This will NOTdo the job, because it will log 'message' on every request.

```
$logger->error('message')
```

and configure a logger with log level = error

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:  rotating_file
            path:  '%kernel.logs_dir%/error.%kernel.environment%.log'
            level: error
            max_files: 10
```